# Add a track at the bottom of the playlist using apple script

Tags: applescript

```
copy "Walk With Me, Lord" to end of playlist "playlistname"
```

I want to add a new track at the bottom of the playlist. Is above code is right?

Answer (score 0):

Any of these should work:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    duplicate track "Some Track" to playlist "Some Playlist"
    copy track "Some Track" to playlist "Some Playlist"
    copy track "Some Track" to end of playlist "Some Playlist"
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not copy songs at the bottom every time but it depends on how the playlist is sorted.
To ensure that every time a song has been added to the playlist, it is added at the bottom no matter how the playlist is sorted (Eg. if the playlist is sorted by Track Name then it wont add the track at the bottom)

IS there a way to sort the playlist by **track index** or if not then check if user has sorted by index, if not then at least we can prompt them to sort it by index number.

Does any one has an example to check if it works?